# VIM: mapping for visual line mode

Tags: vim, mappings

I have this mappings for indenting several lines by pressing TAB in visual mode:

```
vnoremap <Tab> >gv
vnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

But it conflicts with snipmate plugin.
Is there a way to remap TAB button to work only in visual line mode (S-V)?

Comment: Alternativly, I would use '>....' instead of '>>>>'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your mapping commands from `vnoremap` to `xnoremap`:

```
xnoremap <Tab> >gv
xnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

Why?

`v[nore]map` defines mappings both for visual mode *and* for select mode. Because Snipmate puts you into select mode when you are on a placeholder you need to use a more specific mapping command that can't be triggered in select mode: `x[nore]map`.

Actually, you should always use `x[nore]map` instead of `v[nore]map`.